# Security Concerns with Firebase Simple Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I've been using Firebase as a way to synchronize data between a Rails application and a mobile web-kit based application. I've recently been attempting to use the email/password authentication method in lieu of custom auth tokens.

Everything works as expected, but my concern is with user creation and authentication.

Currently, I'm able to create a user, both on Rails (using a self-modified version of the firebase-ruby gem) and through the mobile app, using the firebase node module.

So from the stance of a malicious user, is it correct to assume that I can create a Simple Login user with the JS library (for anyone's firebase instance), and then authenticate with that user, and attempt to read any data that they have stored?

Of course one shouldn't leave their entire Firebase data structure unprotected. So this only works in a situation where one has only set up the default security rules.

Either way, is there any way to prevent anyone from creating users, except for myself (or some other authorized person) without resorting back to custom authentication? I understand the difference between authentication (the server knows who you are) and authorization (the server is letting you in).

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Authenticating a user is not in any way a security risk. In fact: authenticating users against a *well known* identity service, is often a simple first step to discourage (though in no way prevent) abuse. Since Firebase handles the authentication against the third-party service, what harm do you fear from any Joe Random being autenticated?

Comment: I suppose my only concern was with the creation of accounts. I feel that if someone were to decide to create thousands of accounts on my Firebase instance, it would just cause headache for me more than anything. (i.e. Having to delete all the spam users.) That's what I have no control over, as far as I can tell.

Comment: [*Disclaimer: I work for Firebase*]
Why would you have to delete accounts? If you use Facebook/Github/Google accounts with Firebase, nothing is *created* when a user authenticates. Your app just get some "magic" authData for the authenticated user. So unless you have code that stores those users somewhere (e.g. in your Firebase), Firebase handles everything behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Well I'm referring to Email/Password authentication. One is able to create accounts through the ref.createUser() method. I also managed to create users through manual REST requests to https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<SUBDOMAIN>/users with the email and password as a payload. I wanted to be able to create users from my Rails application without having to use the firebase-ruby and JS libraries to get the work done.

Comment: Ah ok, I'd missed the part about your using email/password. There is currently no way to limit email/password to specific users (e.g. domains). If you want something like that, you'll have to use/keep using a custom token generator.

Comment: Understood. I suppose it's not a big concern at the moment. I just wanted to know if I had any options. Thanks Frank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my conversation with Frank, it appears that there is no way to prevent malicious users from creating any number of accounts on a Firebase instance through email/password Simple Login. This doesn't allow them authorization to any data per se, but could be annoying for the SysAdmin/DevOp who was maintaining the Firebase instance.